# How to resolve Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference?

Tags: php, sql, database

```
   if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'addToCart' && !empty($_REQUEST['id'])){
         $productID = $_REQUEST['id'];
         // get product details
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ".$productID;
         $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->execute();

         $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          $itemData = array(
             'id' => $row['id'],
             'name' => $row['name'],
             'price' => $row['price'],
             'qty' => 1
         );

         $insertItem = $cart->insert($itemData);
         $redirectLoc = $insertItem?'viewCart.php':'index.php';
         header("Location: ".$redirectLoc);
```

I am trying to get the the prod name, qty and price -  to be placed on viewCart.php. I am new please help me with this.

Comment: You might want to try using `$_GET` variables. [w3schools.com tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp) contains some useful information about them. BTW You shall not blockquote your code.

Comment: What line is giving your this error? I don't see any methods where you're passing 3 parameters.